# Unit Test (MultipartRequest in Flutter)

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

This is a method I was trying to write a test for. I just want to write a very simple test that would just verify that `send()` was invoked.
But the main trouble maker is the instance `MultipartRequest`.
As you can see, I am directly using the `MultipartRequest` instance, not as a dependency. So, I don't think I am supposed to stub it.
I can easily stub for `getCachedToken()` method as an instance of `TokenValueLocalDataSource` was passed in as a dependency.
What do you think I should do to get my desired test result?

```dart
Future<Unit> addPost({
    File? imageFile,
    String? bodyText,
  }) async {
    if (imageFile != null || bodyText != null) {
      final tokenModel = await tokenValueLocalDataSource.getCachedToken();
      final stringUrl = EnvValues.addPostUrl;

      final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST',
        Uri.parse(stringUrl),
      )..headers.addAll(
          {
            'Authorization': 'Token ${tokenModel.token}',
          },
        );

      if (bodyText != null) {
        request.fields['body'] = bodyText;
      }
      if (imageFile != null) {
        request.files.add(
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path),
        );
      }
      final response = await request.send(); // This needs to verified.
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return unit;
      } else {
        throw ServerException();
      }
    } else {
      throw InvalidRequestException(
        "Both imageFile and bodyText can't be null",
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `http` package, here is my answer:

Since the method itself instantiates the `MultipartRequest` and calls a method from it, it makes the code difficult/impossible to test. So it is easier to use the `Client` class. That is an abstract class that does the same thing and can be mocked. You can see the below example after a few refactoring:

```dart
class ApiClass {
  final http.Client _client;

  const ApiClass(this._client);

  Future<Unit> addPost({File? imageFile, String? bodyText}) async {
    if (imageFile != null || bodyText != null) {
      final tokenModel = await tokenValueLocalDataSource.getCachedToken();
      final stringUrl = EnvValues.addPostUrl;

      final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST',
        Uri.parse(stringUrl),
      )..headers.addAll(
          {
            'Authorization': 'Token ${tokenModel.token}',
          },
        );

      if (bodyText != null) {
        request.fields['body'] = bodyText;
      }
      if (imageFile != null) {
        request.files.add(
          await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', imageFile.path),
        );
      }
      final response = await _client.send(request);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return unit;
      } else {
        throw ServerException();
      }
    } else {
      throw InvalidRequestException(
        "Both imageFile and bodyText can't be null",
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And the test will be something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  group('ApiClass', () {
    late ApiClass apiClass;
    late http.Client client;

    setUp(() {
      client = _MockClient();
      apiClass = ApiClass(client);
      registerFallbackValue(_FakeMultipartRequest());
    });

    test('your test description', () async {
      final response = _MockStreamedResponse();
      when(() => response.statusCode).thenReturn(200);
      when(
        () => client.send(any(
            that: isA<http.MultipartRequest>()
                .having((p0) => p0.files.length, 'has all files', 1))),
      ).thenAnswer((_) async => response);

      final result = await apiClass.addPost(bodyText: 'some text');
      expect(result, equals(unit));
    });
  });
}

class _MockStreamedResponse extends Mock implements StreamedResponse {}

class _FakeMultipartRequest extends Fake implements MultipartRequest {}

class _MockClient extends Mock implements Client {}
```

Comment: Thanks @Elias. Your suggestion did work. Silly of me, I didn't think about using Client instance to invoke send(). 